# 18.04: Kazam with stripes

Tags: kazam

Using [Kazam](https://launchpad.net/kazam) NCC-80102 1.4.5 on 18.04 I get the following stripes

[image: Stripes in the screencast]

Sound works nicely. How can I avoid the stripes?

`sudo lshw -c video | grep configuration` reports:

> configuration: driver=i915 latency=0

How may I troubleshoot and solve this?

Comment: Please run _sudo lshw -c video | grep configuration_  then highlight the resulting text, copy it, return  here, click [edit], and paste it into your question. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only certain resolutions combined with certain formats seem to work.

The AVI-formats seem to be work less often. Instead, both VP8(WEBM) and H264(MP4) work so far with the resolutions I used. (Thus Preferences -> Screencast -> Record with).

Ah, and do not use Wayland (this records only the cursor movements, otherwise all is black). At the login prompt there is Wayland and "nothing" which I assume to be classical X.